# Failed to download repository information-xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu and i get this from the software center :
Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection.
DETAILS:
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.tsl.gr/pool/universe/g/gnutls28/libgnutls28_3.2.11-2ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.tsl.gr/pool/universe/liba/libav/libswscale2_9.11-2ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found

Comment: Have you tried using a different host, i.e. `ubuntu.elsewhere.org` instead of `ubuntu.tsl.gr` ? Chances are the repo content did not get (fully) synced and therefore, the `.deb` file is missing...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mirror you are using does not have the 14.04 packages.

If you go into Settings -> Software and Updates on the first tab labeled "Ubuntu Software" you can select another mirror from the drop down labeled "Download from"